# AngularJS - ng-repeat dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created filters using a dropdown menu and linking that to the list of results.

But I want it to automatically generate from the category column in my db.

So, I have tried this below...

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-show="filteredItems">Filter by Category:
    <select ng-model="search.category" ng-change="filter()" class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list filter: {filter: category} | orderBy : predicate :reverse)">{{data.category}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Please can you see where I am going wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: Better to use ng-options https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: So what does not work?